# How to use the () operator of mser of opencv

Tags: opencv, overloading, operator-keyword, mser

I am using opencv MSER class, cannot compile a use of () operator. I am not a c++ expert, so  post question here, hope somebody can help.

MSER class is defined including a () operator:

```
class CV_EXPORTS_W MSER : public CvMSERParams
{
public:
   ...
    void operator()( const Mat& image,
    CV_OUT vector<vector<Point> >& msers, const Mat& mask ) const;
};
```

The code snippet to use MSER class:

```
Mat yuv;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
cv::MSER mser;
mser(yuv, contours, cv::Mat());
```

at the mser() line, xcode give me this error:

```
No matching function for call to object of type 'cv::MSER'
```

Comment: The ()  operator makes MSER a *functor*. But I think that your problem is simply some wrong/missing headers

Comment: As other functions in this file use opencv correctly, I suppose the opencv header files are correctly included.

Comment: How about `cv::MSER mser(yuv, contours, cv::Mat());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
```

Change it to

```
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
```

The problem is that there is already a Point defined in the Cocoa frameworks, so the compiler is looking for a version of the operator that doesn't exist.